# mod_wsgi.so: Cannot load mod_wsgi.so into server: libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: django, mod-python

I get the following error: when i try to restart the server:

```
[root@lts5srv1 mod_wsgi-2.3]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [FAILED]
Starting httpd: httpd: Syntax error on line 202 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: 
Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: 
libpython2.5.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
                                                           [FAILED]
```

when i type:

```
[root@lts5 /]# ldd /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
    libpython2.5.so.1.0 => /root/epd-5.1.0/lib/libpython2.5.so.1.0 (0x00002b4b53ccf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00002b4b54036000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00002b4b54251000)
    libutil.so.1 => /lib64/libutil.so.1 (0x00002b4b54456000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00002b4b54659000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00002b4b549b1000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003d9f600000)
```

How can i make possible that when i type:

```
[root@lts5srv1 /]# ldd mod_wsgi.so
ldd: ./mod_wsgi.so: No such file or directory
```

..showing the same result?

Comment: Which Python version are you running `python -V`?

Comment: Python 2.5.4 -- EPD 5.1.0, and for the moment i get this error: import os.. ImportError: No module named os.. Do you have any idea of how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me, was: re-installing a new version of Python and the other needed modules inside the new Python site-packages folder. (when you've tried everything and seems that doesn't work try to re-install a new version of python and don't use the default one) 
Follow this link to see the various steps..:
[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320143/python-importerror-no-module-named-os)